# Find the sum of an alias then group by

Tags: mysql, sum, alias

I understand that it is not possible to perform calculations on aliases directly, but is there a way that I could find the sum of my alias(totaltime)? Thanks for the help in advance.

```
    SELECT *,
         TIMEDIFF( time2, time1 ) ,
         TIMEDIFF( time4, time3 ) ,
         ADDTIME( TIMEDIFF( time2, time1 ) ,
         TIMEDIFF( time4, time3 ) ) ,
         TIME_FORMAT( ADDTIME( TIMEDIFF( time2, time1 ) ,
         TIMEDIFF( time4, time3 ) ) , '%H:%i' )
    AS totaltime
        SUM(SELECT(totaltime)) AS sumtotal
    FROM
        timer
    WHERE
        groupid='100'
    AND
        MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(NOW())
    GROUP BY userid
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another layer of abstraction ;)

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(sec_to_time(sum(timecard.totaltime)),'%H:%i' ) FROM 
(
SELECT *,
    TIMEDIFF( out_time, in_time ) , 
    TIMEDIFF( lunch_in, lunch_out ) , 
    ADDTIME( TIMEDIFF( out_time, in_time ) , TIMEDIFF( lunch_in, lunch_out ) ) , 
    ADDTIME( TIMEDIFF( out_time, in_time ) , 
    TIMEDIFF( lunch_in, lunch_out ) )
AS totaltime        
FROM
    timecard
WHERE
    comp_id='129'
AND
    MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(NOW())
GROUP BY emp_id
) timecard
```

Link to fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b33d8/16/0

Comment: I get a SQL ERROR(1248): Every derived table must have its own alias when I add this. Thanks for the response. :)

Comment: The corrected version gave me a value of '0'
Perhaps I did something wrong?

Comment: @user2675057 the new version should `sum` the time difference and display it in hours format

Comment: the new value is now: 00:00:00

Comment: which one is bigger: time4 or time3 ?

Comment: it's supposed to work like a timer: start1, stop2..
then takes a break. start3, stop4

I am hoping to find out the end result.

Comment: @user2675057 please put your code in http://sqlfiddle.com/ so it will be easier to debug - right now all I can do is guess...

Comment: That is awesome! But only small problem: there are two different IDs (100 & 600) why did it only return one value? Shouldn't the group return two different rows? 

I am hoping it would look like this:

EMPID     Total Time
------    ----------
100        00:06
600        00:26

Comment: @user2675057 The group by user-id (inner sql) returns 2 lines, but then in the outer query you SUM so diffs and it returns one line